# Netty neophyte question on WARNING: Failed to release a message: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(freed)

Tags: java, event-handling, netty, nio

I am learning Netty with the Netty In Action book and code example, for the chapter 2 example in https://github.com/normanmaurer/netty-in-action/tree/2.0-SNAPSHOT/chapter2

I added another `AnotherEchoServerHandler` extends `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`, In `AnotherEchoServerHandler.channelRead` method, I update it as:

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
    ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
    System.out.println(
            "Log from AnotherEchoServerHandler that Server received: " + in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
    ctx.write(in);
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx)
        throws Exception {
    ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER)
            .addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
}
```

In the `EchoServer`, I added the new `ChannelHandler` as :

```
 ch.pipeline().addLast(new AnotherEchoServerHandler()).addLast(serverHandler);
```

Along with the other `EchoServerHandler`, I have two `ChannelHandler` now, I'd like to print a message from each `ChannelHandler`, and write back a message to Client from each `ChannelHandler`.

Running the book example with this above change:

On the server side, it logs:

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ echo-server ---
nia.chapter2.echoserver.EchoServer started and listening for connections on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8888
Log from AnotherEchoServerHandler that Server received: Netty rocks!
Server received: Netty rocks!
```

On the Client side, it logs:

```
Client received: Netty rocks!Netty rocks!
```

As you can see I got the information as expected in both sides, but I also saw a WARNING at server side:

```
Mar 30, 2021 6:25:29 PM io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil safeRelease
WARNING: Failed to release a message: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(freed)
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release0(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:101)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:89)
    at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release(ReferenceCountUtil.java:84)
    at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.safeRelease(ReferenceCountUtil.java:109)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:256)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.removeBytes(ChannelOutboundBuffer.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:448)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:856)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:823)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1296)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:776)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:802)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:814)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:794)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:831)
    at nia.chapter2.echoserver.AnotherEchoServerHandler.channelReadComplete(AnotherEchoServerHandler.java:30)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:398)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:380)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:373)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelReadComplete(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1339)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:398)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelReadComplete(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:380)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelReadComplete(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:932)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:139)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748
```

What does this **WARNING** message mean ? **How** can I avoid it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Along with the other EchoServerHandler, I have two ChannelHandler now, I'd like to print a message from each ChannelHandler, and write back a message to Client from each ChannelHandler.

`EchoServerHandler` will also write `msg`. This will cause `msg` be released twice in `ChannelOutboundBuffer`.

You can remove `EchoServerHandler` or call `in.retain()` before write in your `AnotherEchoServerHandler`